# After installing postgres 9.4 on fedora 20, couldn't launch psql

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I have installed postgres 9.4 on fedora 20.
i have followed the steps through the link below
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation

I have started the server using the command

```
service postgresql-9.4 initdb
```

Then I set the auto start using the command

```
chkconfig postgresql-9.4 on
```

I am able to connect with Data base server via pg admin

but I am not able to connect with postgres DB server or SQL command line via terminal

If I enter psql for postgres/or any user, it says command not found.

can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the installation bin directory and use './ExecutableFile' to run when logged in with postgres user.
So, use ./psql when you are in bin directory.

Or you can use "export PATH=path/to/bin/" to avoid using './'